# Comparing two dependent (not matched) rates?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ratio

I'd like to compare the difference in rates obtained by two different methods for the same population. Here's a contrived example (please ignore the semantics):

I randomly survey 5,000 people in the same state and ask how many times they experienced Disease Y over the past year. I also set up a surveillance system in hospitals covering 80% of the state population; this system provides the total number of cases of Disease Y for the same year.

How would I compare the results obtained from these two systems to determine if they are different? The issues that I'm struggling with are that the two groups are: A) dependent, but not matched, and B) population rates (though maybe I should just be looking at the total number of cases reported by each system).